# JS expected a callback value

Tags: javascript, callback, frida

I wrote this JS script to Frida

```
function find_func_address(lib,func)
{

    Module.enumerateExports(lib,
            {onMatch:
                
                function(f){if(f.name==func){
                    console.log("address: " + f.address);}
                    return new NativePointer(f.address);
                
                
            }});
            
}


Interceptor.attach(find_func_address("lib.so","myFunc"), {
    onEnter: function (args) {  
        console.log("enter");
    },
    onLeave: function(retval) {
    
        console.log("exit");
    }
});
```

But I got error : **Error: expected a callback value** on line  : `Interceptor.attach(find_func_address("lib.so","myFunc"), {`

Why is that?

Comment: Your `find_func_address` looks quite complicated, basically the return statement is not for the function but one of the sub-functions you have defined. Why not directly use [Module.findExportByName](https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#module-getexportbyname)?